# parse_str() values are cut for utf-8 words

Tags: php, post

Have problem with parse_str() values are cut and after that the other values donot get saved at all
this happen only with me when I use Arabic characters,it work fine with English words

here is my code

```
$custom = post('custom');
parse_str(post('custom'), $data);
$email = isset($data['email']) && $data['email'] ? $data['email'] : null;
$address = isset($data['address']) && $data['address'] ? $data['address'] : null;
```

Edit

the data come from javascript

```
var formData = $('#form').serialize();
$('.form input[name="custom"]').val(formData);
```

when I

```
alert(formData);
```

I see the data fine

```
item_id=1&address=%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85‌​+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85&email=test%40gmail.com
```

When I try to debug in php

```
$custom = post('custom');

error_log(print_r($custom,true));

parse_str(post('custom'), $data);

error_log(print_r(post('custom'),true));
```

I see the data wrong

```
item_id=1&address=%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%

item_id=1&address==%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%
```

I donot know from where this problem come anymore is it from the serizlize or parse_str

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: form input address and email 
if the address English words its fine and data get saved fine no matter how much large its, but if the address in Arabic words it save 3 or 4 words and cut the rest and donot save even the email.

Comment: use [mb_parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-parse-str.php) instead. most core php string functions aren't unicode aware, and will mangle unicode strings. that's why there's the mb_*() versions, which ARE unicode aware.

Comment: I tried it didn't do anything different

Comment: What is the actual string you're feeding to `parse_str()`?

Comment: in case I use arabic its like this     :  item_id=1&address=%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%

Comment: in case I use English words its like this : item_id=1&address=words+words+words+words+words+words+words+words+words+words+words+words+&email=test%40gmail.com

Comment: I added new info about the problem can you check it now

Answer (score 1):

Since Arabic characters are encoded using more than one byte under UTF-8, you should use multibyte-aware `mb_parse_str()`. (See [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-parse-str.php).)

Answer (score 0):

From what I do understand from parse_str documentation the function expects the string to be url-encoded.

Given your example php isn't the problem if you provide the correct data (see comment below). Consider that if you're using GET, the url can be truncated over 255 bytes, which looks pretty close to your cutout problem.

Comment: tried 
$decodcustom = urldecode(post('custom'));
 mb_parse_str($decodcustom, $data);
same result data get cut

Comment: I added new info about the problem can you check it now

Comment: parse_str() doesn't cut data if you pass the string you get right from javascript.

Comment: This test script shows that php handles it well when it gets the right data:
`<?php
$str  ="item_id=1&address=%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85‌​+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85&email=test%40gmail.com";

$arr;

parse_str($str, $arr);
var_dump($arr);
?>`
If you're using GET, the url string may be truncated if over a certain length.